# error: assignment of member ‘x::x’ in read-only object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants, assignment-operator

I'm having some errors with my code that I can't solve. There errors are:

> error: assignment of member ‘Line::sum’ in read-only object
>     sum = tmp;
>
> error: increment of member ‘Line::number’ in read-only object
>     number++;
>
> error: binding reference of type ‘Line&’ to ‘const Line’ discards qualifiers
>     return(*this);

```
Line & Line :: operator += (const Info & new) const{

    Info * tmp = new Info[number+1];

    for (int p=0; p<number; p++) 
        tmp[p] = sum[p];    // Sin memoria dinámica

    tmp[num_paradas] = new;  // Sin memoria dinámica


    delete [] sum;

    sum = tmp;
    number++;

    return(*this);
}
```

Comment: Unless you are doing something weird, I'm confident `operator+=` shouldn't be `const`. The purpose of the operator is usually to modify the object it's called on, so it doesn't make sense to have it `const`.

Comment: `new` is a reserved keyword. You cannot use it as an identifier name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters (The C++ 17 Standard, 5.10 Identifiers)

> 3 **In addition, some identifiers are reserved for use by C++
>   implementations and shall not be used otherwise**; no diagnostic is
>   required.

Select another identifier instead of the word `new`.

Secondly the member function has the qualifier `const`

```
Line & Line :: operator += (const Info & new) const{
                                              ^^^^^
```

So data members of the corresponding object may not be changed if they are not declared with the specifier `mutable`.

And according to the logic of the `operator +=` the member function should be declared without the qualifier `const`

```
Line & Line :: operator += (const Info & new) {
```

Comment: I think you meant to refer to 5.11 Keywords. The quoted paragraph refers to the use of underscores in identifiers, not keywords. When a keyword is used as an identifier rather than for its rightful purpose, a diagnostic **is** required. Per 5.6 Tokens, "identifier" and "keyword" appear to be disjoint categories. Also, since this may not be obvious to some readers, I think it would be good to explicitly state that the `new` keyword is the one that the OP mistakenly tried to use as an identifier.